# Discord.js - looping an audio resource

Tags: discord, discord.js, ytdl

I'm using discord.js and ytdl-core to play audio from YouTube over discord voice chat. I'm trying to make a 'loop' command that will start looping the song so that when the song ends, it automatically plays again.

I've tried running commands like

```
// Create audio resource
var resource = createAudioResource(stream);

// Subscribe audio player to voice connection
connection.subscribe(player);

// Play audio
player.play(resource);

player.on('idle', () => {
    player.play(resource);
});
```

But I keep getting

`Error: Cannot play a resource that has already ended.`

I've tried recreating the createAudioResource and playing that but I get

`(node:93492) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [PassThrough]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`

Does anybody have any insights on how to loop an audio player bot?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this (there still may be issues with memory leaks, but I haven't been receiving any errors)

I ended up having to re-download the stream, recreate the audio from this new stream, then play it. So my code looks something like this:

```
player.on('idle', () => {
    stream = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});
    resource = createAudioResource(stream);
    player.play(resource);
});
```

**EDIT:** I noticed a potential issue with multiple loop commands adding more and more event listeners, so I added this bit of code before the event listener call.

`if (play.player['_events']['idle']) return;`